# Displaying multiple lines on ggplot with grouped (dodged) bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, linegraph

I have data I need to display in bar and line form on the same graphs. I've been following guidance from https://r-charts.com/evolution/line-graph-multiple-lines-ggplot2/ and https://aledemogr.com/2017/05/29/plots-based-on-un-data-in-r/, which both indicate the data should be in "long" format, where all the values are in the same column and the variable type in another column, as opposed to each variable having its own column.

It almost works, but not quite. The result is:

[image]

If I comment out geom_line() from the ggplot command below, V1 and V2 bars (orange and green) display correctly both on the graph and in the legend. If I comment out geom_col(), V3 and V4 lines display correctly both on the graph and in the legend. But when I include both commands at once, ggplot puts borders around the bars and combines all the variables with the lines in the legend. The two lines themselves are OK on the combined graph except I'll play with the colors later.

Any ideas how to remove the colored borders around the bars and restrict the lines to just V3 and V4? The result I'm expecting for the bars is how they look if you remove the "geom_line()" command (no borders), the lines displayed as they are, and the legend to have a total of four entries: two entries with bars labeled "V1" and "V2" and two simple lines labeled "V3" and "V4".

Here's the code:

```
mydata <- data.frame(month=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,
                             10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10),
                   year=c(2016,2016,2016,2016,2017,2017,2017,2017,
                          2016,2016,2016,2016,2017,2017,2017,2017,
                          2016,2016,2016,2016,2017,2017,2017,2017),
                   var_type=c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V1","V2","V3","V4",
                              "V1","V2","V3","V4","V1","V2","V3","V4",
                              "V1","V2","V3","V4","V1","V2","V3","V4"),
                   var_value=c(1,4,4,3,1,5,4,3,3,22,12,16,
                               3,23,12,16,12,8,7,8,3,8,7,8))

bar_data <- mydata %>%
  filter(water_type == "V1" | water_type == "V2")
line_data <- mydata %>%
  filter(water_type == "V3" | water_type == "V4")

ggplot(line_data,aes(x=month, y=water_val, color=water_type)) +
  geom_col(data=bar_data, aes(fill = water_type), position="dodge") +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("V1 and V2") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,25,10)) +
  xlab("Month") +
  ylab("(cm)") +
  facet_wrap(~year,nrow=2)
```

I'm using R version 3.6.1.

My thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ggplot(line_data,aes(x=month, y=water_val)) +  
   geom_col(data=bar_data, aes(fill = water_type), position="dodge") +
   geom_line(aes(color=water_type)) +
   ggtitle("V1 and V2") +
   scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,25,10)) +
   xlab("Month") +
   ylab("(cm)") +
   facet_wrap(~year,nrow=2)
```

[image: output]